# How to map list of different svg components?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, svg

I have svgs that are required in variables

```
var SVG1 = require('babel-loader!svg-react-loader!../path/SVG1.svg?name=SVG1')
var SVG2 = require('babel-loader!svg-react-loader!../path/SVG2.svg?name=SVG2')
var SVG3 = require('babel-loader!svg-react-loader!../path/SVG3.svg?name=SVG3')
```

I use these variables as a component`<SVG1/>`, because it is a requirement of a svg-react-loader.

I map JSON

```
{this.props.jsonSting.map((item) =>
  <Component key={item.id}
    name={item.name}
    />
)}
```

How should I pass svg variables to `Component` so that with every map iteration in would return next svg.

I tried to add to JSON svg's names (SVG1,SVG2,SVG3) and then past it like this {item.svgname}, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your icons in an array then pass them based on `index` or some other variable:

```
const icons = [<SVG1/>, <SVG2/>, <SVG3/>]

this.props.jsonSting.map((item, index) =>
  <Component key={item.id}
    name={item.name}
    icon={icons[index % 3]}
  />
)}
```

You can also create named collection with an `object` literal:

```
const icons = { SVG1: <SVG1/>, SVG2: <SVG2/>, SVG3: <SVG3/> }

this.props.jsonSting.map(item =>
  <Component key={item.id}
    name={item.name}
    icon={icons[item.svgname]}
  />
)}
```